# how to check all values and show some message

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

I made this 'game', and now I want to show some message (winner) when are all values of input's equals zero, and I want to show message when 3 field values are less than 0.

examples:
when the fields are like this (connect link)

```
http://prntscr.com/3jgvz6
```

then user is winner, but when it is like this (just two fields with 0)

```
http://prntscr.com/3jgw6f
```

then user is automatically loser.

Link to jsbin : http://jsbin.com/kezesefu/1

My code is so long to put it here..

User lose the game when of 25 fields are just two 0. Ex.

```
2 3 1 2 0
2 2 1 1 1
3 0 3 1 2
2 3 4 1 2
```

There is just two zeros, so user is loser.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: I do not understand the criteria for the losing scenario.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to StackOverflow! Please add some code and details in your questions instead of just links. We do not like to follow just any random link.

Comment: @undefined: It appears that the OP is asking for help on adding additional implementation, so this is off-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @Jamal I meant "I recommend posting a question on  codereview.stackexchange.com after solving the current issue".

Comment: @undefined: The original comment didn't state that, and askers are usually quick to post on the linked site.  Since you've clarified it, hopefully the asker will keep it in mind.  We do also need the code in the question, as the first comment suggests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working [demo](http://jsbin.com/citoguzo/3)

Try adding this to the **end** of your document ready function:

```
function verifyWinningConditions () {
    var nonZeroBoxes = 25;
    $('input').each(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 0) {
            nonZeroBoxes--;
        }
    });

    if (nonZeroBoxes == 0) {
        alert('WINNER!! All 25 boxes are 0!');
    }

    if(nonZeroBoxes >= 23) {
        alert('LOSER! Only 2 out of 25 boxers were 0!');
    }
}

$('input').on('click', verifyWinningConditions);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var inputs = $('input'), sum;
$('button').on('click', function(){
  sum=0;
  inputs.each(function(){
  sum += +$(this).val();
 });
if(sum > 0){
  console.log('not all zeros');
 }else{
  console.log('all zeros');
}
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/wuvazira/2/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kezesefu/2/edit)**

```
$('.inputi').click(function() {
   var counter = 0; 
   $(".inputi").each(function() { 
     if(this.value==0){
         counter= counter+1;
       }
   });

   if(counter==0) {
     // show message here
     alert("You won!");
   } 
   if(counter < 3 & counter >0) {
    //show message when 3 field values are less than 0.
    alert("Sorry, you lost the game");
   }
});
```

Comment: move counter = 0, inside the click event

Comment: Updated the link in my answer also. Hope it satisfies your condition :)

Comment: I cannot try with all zeros, but with less than 3 it works. Thank you :D

Comment: I cannot vote up, because my reputation is under 15. :s

Comment: have this condition   if(counter < 3 & counter >0) { and it will work for 0, you can check